# Unity unable to publish to Play Console - Invalid app signature

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

[image]

Here is what I get after waiting for the upload. I'm using latest Unity (2017.3.0f3)  with JDK 8 (because 9 wasn't even building). Now the project builds but I can't deploy it to the console nor can I to the Emulator.

Note, I did assign my keystore file and I did write the passwords. I'm not uploading a development build, I double checked that. For the build I was using the old .25 tools (inside the sdk folder I replaced the existing ones). I did that so that I can get a build.

I looked for the error message of course, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be your app signing step failed while producing final apk.

[As mentioned here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html), try resigning your apk with below sample commands

```
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --out my-app-release.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

and validate same using

```
apksigner verify my-app-release.apk
```

Comment: Does this work on Unity with an already created `apk`? The article talks about releasing from Android Studio.
if so, where do I open powershell/cmd to perform this?

Comment: yes it will, you can run wherever you want, just give correct paths of your keystore and your apk

Comment: And with powershell? :D for no apparent reason the cmd opens and closes immediately. I guess a reinstall is due.

Comment: Sorry I keep asking back :( I have a `˙.keystore` file only (and it used to work fine for many uploads) and no `.jks` file. am I missing something?

Comment: In the meantime I read the article too but it's unclear what `my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk` is. The other apk was my `build3.apk` I built using Unity.

Comment: It should look like this
"apksigner sign --ks your_key.keystore --out signed-app.apk build3.apk"

"signed-app.apk" will be your signed apk

Comment: The remaining problem is the missing signer - apksigner : The term 'apksigner' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
 Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ apksigner sign --ks agirogames.uploadBug.keystore --out build3_s.apk  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (apksigner:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: but I used this: https://shatter-box.com/knowledgebase/android-apk-signing-tool-apk-signer/    should work too? it says signed, checking via emulator if it runs.

Comment: The apksigner tool, available in revision 24.0.3 and higher of the Android SDK Build Tools

Above tool seems to be fine, but make sure you use your same old keystore for signing apk, else google play dev console will not allow you to upload

Comment: I'm using that. By the way on first try I'm just trying to run it on the Emulator but that doesn't work either :( not to mention I made a clean new empty project and it fails too on the emulator (with its clean new keystore). I filed a bug report to unity as well

Comment: "The screen cannot be set to the number of lines and columns specified."
  I think it is an error with windows 10 :/ Or have you seen anything like so?

Comment: then I'm resetting windows :D

Comment: Thought I let you know, resetting windows actually did the trick, though I had to use java 8 and android sdk tool 25.something.